# Oracle APEX - the value does not carry over when using Redirect to Page

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a field on my page that I want to carry over to another page in the application.
On a button click I use "Redirect to Page in application" and set the page number to 2.

Now I want to carry over the value P1_MY_ID to page 2, so I used Set Items for target page:

```
NAME            VALUE
_________       _______
P2_RECORD_ID    &P1_MY_ID.
```

On Page 2, P2_RECORD_ID is a Select List filled from a shared LOV and its source is set to a database column.

Once page 2 opens, I do not see the value P2_RECORD_ID in a session state. 
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you see the item name and value in the URL of the page? If so, this might be a problem with the select list source.

Comment: Why is that a problem? How can I fix that?

Comment: I wanted to distinguish if this is a problem with the source or target page, therefore the check in the URL. From your explanation I suspected the target page. I think Jeffreys answer is a good explanation for the possible cause.

Comment: the second page is a modal dialog, so i cannot check the url...

Comment: You are able to check that in the network tab of your developer console in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Thanks! I do see P2_RECORD_ID in the URL but without a value

Answer (score 2):

Typically if an item has Source **Type** = **Database Column**, the Source **Used** will be **"Always, replacing any existing value in session state"**. This means that on page load the item's value will be overwritten by the **Automatic Row Fetch** process.

In your particular case, it seems the value you are passing is the record ID - if this is a unique identifier for a record to retrieve from the database, you need to check that it has been set as the **Primary Key Item** in the automatic row fetch process.

Comment: that is not primary key for the automatic row fetch

Answer (score 0):

Interesting but I just switch places for the items I am passing and it worked... Not sure why it worked but I'll take that...

Comment: I know it's been a long time but I have exactly the same problem. Can u explain what did you mean by switch places? or did you find the reason for why this is happening?

Comment: You know how when setting a target as another page you have an option to set items?

A place where you specify item name and item value. For example you have

P1_ITEM1  &ITEM1.
P1_ITEM2  &ITEM2.

Putting Item1 first and Item2 second. Switching places simply means you first put Item2 and then Item1. Provided you are passing more than one item to the target page

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I found out my problem is not solvable because the button renders, with all its values, only on page load